# standard steps to Restart Seconday server in Logshipping setup

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have to reboot my Logshipping secondary server.
what are the steps need to be taken on primary and secondary servers to make the reboot clean and without hurting logshipping.

env : SQL server 2005 SP4  64bit
windows server 2008 R2 enterprise

Comment: Why not just re-initialize log shipping? You've probably already spent more time worrying about how you're going to avoid that than it will actually take.

Answer (score 3):

What I usually do with our 15-minute log shipping secondary servers is just wait until the last log is copied over and restored. Then you can reboot the secondary server (assuming that by server you mean a separate physical server). As soon as the secondary comes back up, it will copy over the missing transaction log file and restore them.

We restore our secondary in STANDBY, so some people query them once in a while, just make sure you let the appropriate people know that you're about to reboot the server.

Comment: By the time secondary comes up if there are 2 log backup files generated on Primary, how will the copy job identify and copy and restore in sequence.

Comment: That's no problem. Every transaction log has a log sequence number (LSN) -- [Log Sequence Numbers and Restore Planning](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190729(v=sql.105).aspx)